# Being Galois stable under completion?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

Let $R$  a Dedekind Domain, $K = \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ the fraction field, $L/K$ a finite galois extension, $R'$ the integral closure of $R$ in $L$. Then $R'$ is Dedekind again.

Let $\mathfrak{p} \subset R$ a maximal ideal. Let $\mathfrak{P} \subset R'$ be a prime ideal lying over $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R'$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{P} | \mathfrak{p}R'$).

Consider respectively the adic completions $L_\mathfrak{P} / K_\mathfrak{p}$, does it hold in general that this extension is galois again? If not, which additional conditions are needed?

We used this statement in some proves during our lecture of algebraic number theory, but it was never shown. Possibly it's a stupid question and I've just not found the right angle to look at it yet.

Comment: Write $L = K(\alpha)$. The main point is to show $L_{\mathfrak P} = K_{\mathfrak p}(\alpha)$. If $L/K$ is Galois then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is separable and has a full set of roots in $L$. All those roots are in the larger field $L_{\mathfrak P}$ too, and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K_{\mathfrak p}$ is a factor of its minimal polynomial over $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, the extension $L_{\frak P}/K_{\frak p}$ is Galois with Galois group the decomposition group $$Z(\frak{P}/\frak{ p})=\{\sigma\in \mathrm{Gal}(\mathrm {L/K})\hspace{2mm}|\hspace{2mm} \sigma(\frak P)=\frak P\}.$$
for the proof you can find it in **J.Neukirch Algebraic Number Theory.** Chapter II.